# Eclipse plugin development - ToolItem strange behavior at enabling

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, e4

I defined a HandledToolItem in fragment.e4xmi :

```xml
<fragments xsi:type="fragment:StringModelFragment" xmi:id="_rva08KK6Eeealvq0OCaXXw" featurename="trimContributions" parentElementId="org.eclipse.e4.legacy.ide.application">
    <elements xsi:type="menu:TrimContribution" xmi:id="_NDOigKK8Eeealvq0OCaXXw" elementId="xyz.trimcontribution.0" parentId="org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar" positionInParent="after=additions">
      <children xsi:type="menu:ToolBar" xmi:id="_NXC2YKK8Eeealvq0OCaXXw" elementId="xyz.toolbar.1" accessibilityPhrase="ToolItems1">
        <children xsi:type="menu:HandledToolItem" xmi:id="_dOkvwKK8Eeealvq0OCaXXw" elementId="xyz.handledtoolitem.1" label="Item1" iconURI="platform:/plugin/xyz-plugin/resources/icons/toolbar/Item1.png" tooltip="" enabled="false" command="_SALb4JItEee5yvRIuSvsRg"/>
       </children>
    </elements>
  </fragments>
```

I can enable/disable toolItem with setEnable method, but when I click some elsewhere on the UI toolItem state always change to enabled, regardless which state is had before.

I work in Eclipse E4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enable status of a tool or menu item is updated from the current handler's `@CanExecute` method regularly so you can't just call `setEnabled` to change its state. If there isn't a `@CanExecute` method, `true` is assumed.

Instead implement a `@CanExecute` method in the handler that returns the enablement state:

```java
@CanExecute
public boolean canExecute()
{
  return // TODO enabled state
}
```

If you want to change the enabled state during the main `@Execute` method of the handler you may need to force Eclipse to call the `@CanExecute` method. You do this using a special topic of the event broker:

```java
@Execute
public void execute(MHandledToolItem mitem, IEventBroker eventBroker)
{
   ... other code

   // Update enablement
   eventBroker.send(UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC, mitem.getElementId());
}
```

Comment: It's working, but in a strange way. I have same Commands for menuItems as well. When click on "Menu point" @CanExecute is called, but when  eventBroker.send executed, didn't.

Comment: I tried this also: eventBroker.send(UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC, UIEvents.ALL_ELEMENT_ID);

Comment: UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC will only call the can execute for tool items. For menu items the can execute only needs to be called when the menu is shown so the request enablement doesn't need to call the can execute.

Comment: Now it's working, I forgot to add  "org.eclipse.e4.ui.services" bundle. Thanks!